# Swift - self.init() within class method not creating correct type

Tags: swift, initialization

I have a class hierarchy where `ClassB` inherits from `ClassA`

Static variable `solitaire` is defined on `ClassA`

```
static var solitaire: ClassA!
```

class function `createdSolitaire()` is defined on `ClassA`

```
class func createSolitaire() {

  solitaire = self.init()
}
```

When I call `ClassB.createSolitaire()`, var `solitaire` is set to an instance of `ClassA`, not `ClassB`.

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you.

Code:

```
class ClassA {

static var shared: ClassA!

class func createSolitaire() {
    shared = self.init()
} 
}

class ClassB : ClassA {
}
```

To reproduce the problem, invoke ClassB.createSolitaire() from wherever...e.g., PlayGround or viewLoaded method in a viewController.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: Example added to original post.

Comment: The `shared = self.init()` line  does not compile in my Xcode 10: “Constructing an object of class type 'ClassA' with a metatype value must use a 'required' initializer”

Comment: So I don't have Xcode 10 (running 9.4) but that was enough of a hint. I simply added an empty init() method to ClassA with "required" and now self.init() returns the correct object (an instance of ClassB, in my example). Somewhat unsettling that that fixed it, but whatever :-). Many thanks!

required init() {
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Martin R's comment, I found the fix:

I simply added an empty init() method to ClassA with "required" and now self.init() returns the correct object (an instance of ClassB, rather than ClassA, in my example). Somewhat unsettling that that fixed it, but whatever.

i.e.

required init() {
}